# Why does Nuget packages come with AssemblyBinding?

Tags: nuget, azure-storage, nuget-package, azure-storage-queues, azure-storage-files

I am using the `Azure.Storage.Queues` nuget package and it came with assemblyBinding; which I didn’t realise was a thing.

I was initially using this package to build a .netstandard2.0 class library, and using `CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies` to publish all assemblies referenced by my project.
[image]

With this code:

```
Azure.Storage.Queues.QueueClient.SendMessageAsync("someMessage",default);
```

I kept getting this error

`Could not load file or assembly 'System.Buffers, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Visual Studio shows that the `Azure.Storage.Queues` package is using `System.Buffer - 4.5.1` nuget package which contains the `System.Buffer.dll, v4.0.3.0` assembly but when the code is executed, it tries to find the `System.Buffer.dll, v4.0.2.0`; as shown in the error.

This was impossible to figure this out when I was working on the class library project, I only realised that there are bindings involved with this package when I imported this package to a console app at which point it updated the `App.config` file.
[image]

Also the ref folder in the `System.Buffer 4.5.1` nuget package contains the `System.Buffer.dll, v4.0.2.0` version of the assembly and the lib folder in the package `System.Buffer.dll, v4.0.3.0`.

Can someone please help me understand

- if there is anything in a Nuget package that can tell me if it needs any assemblyBinding.
- why does the `Azure.Storage.Queues.QueueClient.SendMessageAsync` method trying to use the `System.Buffer.dll, v4.0.2.0` version of the lib?

Comment: Binding redirects are only a thing on .NET Framework. .NET Core and .NET 5+ no longer have this concept, and will accept any assembly version that is equal to or higher version than the referencing assembly expects. The problem here is that your bin directory ends up with a lower version than what one of the other assembly requires. Generally this should not happen, so I would need a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to investigate why the higher version is not being copied.

Comment: I think the assemblyBindings are automatically created because the version of the nuget packaged being referenced in the project does not contain the version of the assembly referenced by the Azure project.

Comment: I have a project targeting  ```<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>```, the System.Buffer 4.5.1 does not support this library. 

It does support 45 and 46; the unizpped nuget packaged contained ```System.Buffer, 4.0.3.0``` version of the assembly.

So, it might be that Visual Studio found code that needed ```System.Buffers,4.0.2.0``` but the nuget package only had the ```System.Buffers,4.0.3.0```  version and created the assembly binding config.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question, programmatically you can use reflection to determine the referenced assemblies via System.Reflection.Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies().

If you want to analyze it with graphical tools, I recommend JetBrains dotPeek which shows you content and references of assemblies very easy (as most people I know have JetBrains Resharper Ultimate already installed alongside their IDE).

[image: JetBrains dotPeek System.Collections.Concurrent example]